# HTTP error when executing methods in HDInsight .NET SDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, hive, azure-hdinsight

I am having some problems when executing several methods of the .NET SDK for managing Azure HDinsight.

In particular I am having problems when trying to execute Hive Jobs from an MVC app deployed in Azure as Webapp.

At least, these two methods fail:

- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.JobSubmission.HDInsightHadoopClient.**GetJob**
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.JobSubmission.HDInsightHadoopClient.**CreateHiveJob**

In both cases,  I can see (following the exception stack trace) that the inner(most) method that is failing is:

- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Framework.Core.Library.WebRequest.**HttpClientAbstraction**

The exception message is: **"An error occurred while sending the request".**

I have tried to find an IIS server running in the HDInsight cluster (the cluster, after all, is but several connected Windows Server VMs) because I thought that mi MVC application was sending http requests (when using the SDK methods...) to another  application deployed there. I wanted to change some parameters (timeout?) and see the IIS logs, but I didn't find an IIS running in the machines of my cluster.

Does anybody know  what can be causing the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I know this isn't the most direct answer to your question, but you may want to consider using the latest .NET SDK packages for HDInsight:

- Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight
- Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsightJob

Here is a helpful tutorial on how to use the new SDK: [Submit Hadoop jobs programmatically](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-submit-hadoop-jobs-programmatically/)

I hope this helps! If you have more details about your original solution that you are encountering problems with, please post a bit more additional context / surrounding code to help out.